# Asymptotic behavior of coefficient of a complicated generating function

Tags: co.combinatorics, cv.complex-variables, asymptotics, generating-functions

Given a generating function
$$H(z)=\sum_{m=0}^\infty h_m z^m =\frac{P F(z)}{1-(1-P)F(z)}$$
where $0<P\leq 1$ and 
$$F(z)=1-\frac{\pi z\sqrt{c}}{6\boldsymbol{\mathrm{K}}(k')} $$
in which $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{K}}$ is a complete integral of the first kind and $k'=\sqrt{\frac{2(b-a)}{c}}$.

$a,b,c$ are given as:
$$a=\frac{3}{z}+1-\sqrt{3+\frac{6}{z}} \qquad \text{and} \qquad b=\frac{3}
{z}+1+\sqrt{3+\frac{6}{z}}\ ,\\$$
$$c=(a+1)(b-1).$$

I'm interested in the large $m$ behavior of $h_m$. So first i need to get the inverse z-transform of $H(z)$ given by the contour integration
$$h_m=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_c \frac{H(z)}{z^{m+1}}dz $$
where c is a closed contour encircling $z=0$ anticlockwise once, which lies within the circle of convergence of $H(z)$.

How to extract the leading order behavior (first few term) of $h_m$ by

(i) solving the above integration or

(ii) if it's not possible, directly from $H(z)$.

In method (i), i'm stuck at contour path choosing step as the function $H(z)$ have some complicated branch cuts (as indicated by plotting the function on complex plane using Mathematica) connecting the singularities (at $z=-3,0,1$), probably due to the nested root in $k'$ and $c$.

In method (ii), i'm not sure whether techniques like Tauberian theorems and Darboux's Theorem are able to return asymptotic behavior up to several terms or not. If they do, how?

For simplicity, one can look at the case when $P=1$.

Comment: Why do you think the series expansion around $z=0$ exists? For example, $$k'=2\,\sqrt {{1\sqrt {3+6\,{z}^{-1}} \left( 9\,{z}^{-2}+2\,\sqrt {3+6\,{z
}^{-1}}-3 \right) ^{-1}}}.
 $$

Comment: I get $F(z) = z^2/6 + z^3/18 + z^4/24 + z^5/36 + 43z^6/1944 + 17z^7/972 + \cdots$

Comment: @Somos: Can you elaborate how you get it?

Comment: @user64494  I used $\texttt{z=24*x^2; u=3/z+1; v=sqrt(6/z+3); a=u-v; b=u+v;}$
$\texttt{c=(a+1)*(b-1); m=1-2*(b-a)/c; F=1-sqrt(c)*agm(1,sqrt(m))*z/3;}$

Comment: @user642639 Why did you use $k'$ instead of simply $k$? It does not matter what you called it, but still.

Comment: I could have use k, dint give much thought as I transferred the formula from the original text. Sorry if that causes confusion. If you are interested in the origin, check out eq 5 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.1435

Comment: @user642639 Thanks for that reference. It makes more sense now.

Comment: Turn out by singularity analysis I manage to get some asymptotic form of the solution.